# How can I implement in android Evernote 'New Note' floating button like animation?

Tags: android, animation, evernote

I want to implement an evernote android app floating plus button type animation, which pops some icons vertically. I suppose they use the Spring Rebound API but can I get a complete working example to do it.

Comment: Are you developing on Android 5.0?

Comment: @VipulKumar Yes Vipul.

Comment: I kind of believed it was a native functionality for FAB in Android. But you can check out this library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button Not quite what you want maybe, but useful.

Comment: Hey ishant were you able to figure this out

Comment: @war_Hero yes, you can follow the link above by VipulKumar, its working https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Comment: @Ishant were you able to do it exactly like Evernote? I'm talking about blurring the background when the menu is expanded, and having the FAB morph into another one with a label (New Note) beside it ??

Comment: @SilviaHisham yes, I was,but you need to do a bit trick for your blur effect

Comment: @Ishant can you please post how you did it as an accepted answer to your question so that others can benefit from it? specially the part about morphing the floating button into another one with a label like Evernote does.